# How change Biblatex references to my own style?

Tags: biblatex, biber

I'm very new using Latex (TeXShop 4.25) and while I have been writing my thesis I had some problems with my references. I'm using  `biblatex` and Biber and I need the references as follows:

> Author.(year)"Title". Journal;volume(number):pages.

For example:

> Baldwin I., Halitschke R., Paschold A., von Dahl CC. y Preston CA. (2006) “Volatile signaling in plant–plant interactions:‘talking trees’ in the genomics era”. Science; 311(5762):812-815.

The closest style that I found is authoryear, and this is the code that I made:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
            style=authoryear,
            sorting=nyt,
            sortlocale=de_DE,
            natbib=true,
            url=false,
            doi=false,
            isbn=false,
            maxcitenames=2, 
            maxbibnames=9, 
            eprint=false]
            {biblatex} ç
\addbibresource{References.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{baldwin06}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

And this is what the programs print me:

> Baldwin, I.T, Halitschke R., Anja P., von Dahl C.C. and Preston C. A. (2006). Volatile Signaling in Plant-Plant Interactions: Talking Trees in the Genomics Era.Science 311, 5762, pags. 812-815.

As you may notice I want to

- eliminate the first comma ("Baldwin, I.T"),
- put the title in double quotes,
- put a semicolon after journal,
- print the number in parenthesis after volume and
- show a colon before the pages.

Does anyone know how to customize this reference?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please note that is preferable to ask only about one specific issue per question as that makes questions more valuable for future visitors (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7425/35864). ...

Comment: ... Many of the details you need for you style are interesting in their own right and some might even have answers on this site already that you are more likely to find if you look for them decoupled from the rest.

Comment: You should have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/15925 to solve some of these issues.

Comment: Could you please also include the source of the `.bib` entry? Normally titles of `@article`s are printed in quotation marks (their exact style may depend on the language settings and `csquotes` if loaded), so if you don't get any that is suspicious.

Comment: Thanks to Andrew, moewe and specially to Bernard. I have customize bibliography as I wish!
What you have done Bernard was insane! Thanks you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{References.bib}
    @article{baldwin06,
    Author = {Baldwin, I. and Halitschke, R. and Paschold, A. and von Dahl, C.C. and Preston, C.A.},
    Journal = {Science},
    Number = {5762},
    Pages = {812--815},
    Title = {Volatile signaling in plant–plant interactions:‘talking trees’ in the genomics era},
    Volume = {311},
    Year = {2006}}
\end{filecontents}
% Baldwin I., Halitschke R., Paschold A., von Dahl CC. y Preston CA. (2006) “Volatile signaling in plant–plant interactions:‘talking trees’ in the genomics era”. Science; 311(5762):812-815.

\usepackage[backend=biber,
            style=authoryear,
            sorting=nyt,
            sortlocale=de_DE,
            natbib=true,
            url=false,
            doi=false,
            isbn=false,
            maxcitenames=2,
            maxbibnames=9,
            eprint=false]
            {biblatex}
\addbibresource{References.bib}

\usepackage{xpatch}

 \xpatchbibdriver{article}{%
  \usebibmacro{in:}}{}{}{}

\xpatchbibmacro{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \setunit*{\addspace}}{%
  \setunit*{\addsemicolon\addspace}}{}{}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}% number of a journal

\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{pages}{#1}

\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit*{\space}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}

\renewbibmacro*{note+pages}{%
  \printfield{note}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\addspace}%
  \printfield{pages}%
  \newunit}

\begin{document}

\cite{baldwin06}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]